# Clases Inmutables en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

necesito modificar la siguiente clase para convertirla en una clase inmutable, sin heredar de tuple, namedtuple o dataclass. Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma, pero no es válida dado que pese a que devuelve el resultado esperado, se puede modificar el valor de los atributos, así como añadir nuevos atributos con el método **dict**, pese al uso del método **slots**

```
class Operacion:
      """Una clase que debe ser modificada para ser inmutable sin """
    __slots__ = ()  

    def __init__(self, operandoA, operandoB):    
        super().__setattr__("operandoA", operandoA)
        super().__setattr__("operandoB", operandoB)

    def producto(self):

        return self.operandoA * self.operandoB

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Ejemplos
    r = Operacion(25, 78)
    print(r.operandoA) # Prints 25
    print(r.operandoB)  # Prints 78
    print(r.producto()) # Prints 1950
```

Answer (score 1):

te ha faltado hacer una cosa. Usando `__slots__` limitas la creacion de nuevos atributos (que por cierto has olvidado enumerar en tu codigo!), pero tienes que hacer un override del metodo `__setattr__` para que no te deje modificar los valores.

Seria algo asi:

```
class Operacion:
    """Una clase que debe ser modificada para ser inmutable sin """
    __slots__ = ('operandoA', 'operandoB')  

    def __init__(self, operandoA, operandoB):    
        super(Operacion, self).__setattr__("operandoA", operandoA)
        super(Operacion, self).__setattr__("operandoB", operandoB)

    def producto(self):
        return self.operandoA * self.operandoB

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            """
            Hacemos un override del setter de atributos
            """
            if name in self.__slots__:
                msg = "'%s' no tiene permiso para sobreescribir %s" % (self.__class__,name)
                raise AttributeError(msg)

            else:
                msg = "'%s' no tiene atributo %s" % (self.__class__,name)
                raise AttributeError(msg)
```

Fijate que lo he hecho con una condicion `if` para que distinga si estas modificando un atributo ya existente o bien intentando crear uno nuevo.

Ejemplo 1:

```
r = Operacion(25, 78)
r.operandoA = 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-b903f542a2a0> in <module>
----> 1 r.operandoA = 1

<ipython-input-132-d3502f09ce61> in __setattr__(self, name, value)
     18                 msg = "'%s' no tiene permiso para sobreescribir %s" % (self.__class__,
     19                                                     name)
---> 20                 raise AttributeError(msg)
     21 
     22             else:

AttributeError: '<class '__main__.Operacion'>' no tiene permiso para sobreescribir operandoA
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
r.operandoC = 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-68869d3bd2f8> in <module>
----> 1 r.operandoC = 1

<ipython-input-132-d3502f09ce61> in __setattr__(self, name, value)
     24                 msg = "'%s' no tiene atributo %s" % (self.__class__,
     25                                                     name)
---> 26                 raise AttributeError(msg)
     27 
     28 

AttributeError: '<class '__main__.Operacion'>' no tiene atributo operandoC
```

Comment: Aún así, hay trucos para saltarse las restricciones: `object.__setattr__(r, "operandoA", 1)` .... `Operacion.operandoC = 1`. Lo de la _inmutabilidad_ en python no está bien llevada.